# Draw on Canvas using Default Text

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

i m using croquis library to draw on canvas. its working fine

Scenario: 
i want to show some kind of **watermark or placeholder** on canvas before drawing and on click i want to clear that placeholder . Can some one tell me what needs to be done

Any help will be appreciated

Regards

Comment: well i have tried to put label with absolute position but that push to me to click twice . thats why i thought to fix it in library . Croquis add layers for drawing  now m thinking of add something there but its a third party library  its difficult to make changes in it

Comment: Can you paste your code, please? Maybe we can fix the problem with clicking twice, or search for another solution, but it would be nice to have a starting point :)

Comment: Basically m looking for an idea to get it done as to paste all code wld bit difficult

Comment: I'd just use transparency on the top layer and then make sure it doesn't steal focus/clicks. But please post a [mcve] to help us help you.

Comment: I don't use Croquis so there might be a simple solution within it's API. But alternatively, you can just use CSS `position:absolute` to place a watermark/placeholder img element on top of the canvas and then remove that img when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to initialise your canvas with a watermark and clear it on the first click.  I'm not familiar with the Croquis library, but a plain JavaScript solution could be something like the function below - perhaps you can amend it to fit your project...

```
var firstFlag = true;
var canvas = $('#canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function watermark(e) {
    if (firstFlag) {
        /* firstFlag === true -> add text to canvas */
        ctx.fillStyle = '#999';
        ctx.font('bold 20px Serif');
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillText('Watermark Text', canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

        /* reset firstFlag */
        firstFlag = false;
    } else {
        /* firstFlag === false -> clear Canvas */           
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        /* remove eventListener */
        canvas.removeEventListener('click',watermark,false);
    }
}

---

/* when the page is ready 
   add EventListener to canvas element and... */
canvas.addEventListener('click',watermark,false);
/* ...initialise the canvas by calling watermark() */
watermark(false);
```

The `watermark()` function will be called twice; once when called by code (last line) and once when the canvas element is clicked.  The first call to `watermark()` adds "Watermark Text" to the center of the canvas: the second call (on click) clears the canvas, and removes the 'click' `eventListener` so that that `watermark()` is never called again, leaving the canvas clean and ready for whatever else you want to do next.

Hope this helps.  :)